# How do I repeat a piece of code

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, code-optimization

For a school assignment I need to make a LED blink on/of 3 times then stop. 
Now I have come up with the following code:

[image: Repeat!]

I think it's ''clean'' enough for what it has to do, but I have a feeling that here must be a easier way to make the LED blink 3 times.

**Question is: Is there a way to reapeat the part of code 3 times without copy&pasting it?**

Comment: Other than with a loop?

Comment: Google "for loop C++".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The thing is that it has to stop after 'blinking' 3 times. And there is no way to stop the loop, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: And? There are loops that can do that. Or have you not looked at any C++ tutorials yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Only thing I found so far is a Exit(0); which makes the program stop. But then I still have to copy paste the code 3x becuase the loop otherwise stops after 1 on 1 off loop.

Comment: Thank you for his code.. just some follow-up.
If i want to stop the flashing when button press, what code need to add.
ex: LED flashing for 30s then when i press the button it will stop. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can use a loop. a classic for loop in C++ looks like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    // content in between these brackets
}
```

where n is the amount of times you want to loop

you can also instantiate the `i` before the loop.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    //content here
}
```

The code below should work. Toy around with it and see what you get.

```
int ledPin = 13;
int delayPeriod = 500;


void setup(){
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        delay(delayPeriod);
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        delay(delayPeriod);
    }
```

another approach you can do is using a while loop. These kinds of loops will loop until a given parameter has been met. In your case you want an LED to stop blinking after 3 times.

```
int start = 0;
int stop = 3;

while (start <= stop){
    //content here
}
```

While loops will continue to go as long as the parameter is true. This means something like `while(1)` will continue to run forever.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the Int i; function and it works perfectly!

Comment: @tisaconundrum have you missed an increment or decrement in your while loop?

Comment: How can I change to code to work with if and else statements, so it wil work in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to declare a function. This method will give you more chance of using it in various ways.

```
    int LED_PIN = 13;

    void flashing(size_t times=1) { // By default it will flash once, you can chance this into your desire
        int delayPeriod = 500;
        for (size_t loop = 0; loop < (times*2); ++loop) {
          digitalWrite(LED_PIN, (loop % 2)?HIGH:LOW);// Use Modulus
          delay(delayPeriod);
        } // Thanks to [Matt][1] and [Edgar Bonet][2] for their comments
    }

    void setup() {
        pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
        flashing(3);
    }

    void loop() {
        // Do something here
    }
```

Comment: I also came up with the idea of using a function, but you have to consider the overhead of calling it,  In this case I don't think its worth the cost.  Normal coding standards frown upon placing two statements on a single line.  Off the top of my head I couldn't say if a while or for was more efficient, but personally for a fixed number of iterations I would go for a for loop, if I had to do a while loop then I would set I to zero so I could do `(i<times)` which would be quicker than what you have.  All that said, its still a good answer.

Comment: A for loop is definitely better in terms of legibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at optimising the 4 lines of code inside you loop:

```
const int ledPin = 13;
const int delayPeriod = 500;
const size_t count = 3;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    for (size_t loop = 0; loop < (count*2); ++loop) // size_t because variable is never negative.
    {  // Two time count, because you only have half the code
        digitalWrite(ledPin, (loop % 2)?HIGH:LOW);// Use Modulus
        delay(delayPeriod);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late respons! Thanks you for helping out, I will try this methode later tonight! I already made my code work with the previouse answer. This methode may be easier to read for others. Def going to take a look at it. Thanks again, Really appreciate the time and effort you took for responding!